# Ionic 2 : Reduce app boot time

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic2, splash-screen

I have to build an ionic app and I really need to reduce boot time.
Currently, In my honor 6x pro I wait for 14 second.

I try to run my app with

```
ionic run android --prod
```

But nothing different append.

I use Ionic v2.1.8

I really don't know what I can do, but 14 seconds is a bit too long. Somebody has an idea ?

ps : I am calling enableProdMode() in my main.ts file.

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
```

My app.component.ts file :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ViewController, App, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import {LoginPage} from "../pages/login/login";
import {PData} from "../providers/p-data";
import {CNotification} from "../classes/CNotification";
import {PTranslate} from "../providers/p-translate";
import {CheckUserPage} from "../pages/check-user/check-user";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = CheckUserPage;
  display_handled : boolean = false;
  diplayed_notifications_handled: CNotification[] = [];
  position : number = 0;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public pdata: PData, public translate: PTranslate, public app: App, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });

    platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      let nav = app.getActiveNav();
      let activeView: ViewController = nav.getActive();

      if(activeView != null){
        if(nav.canGoBack()) {
          nav.pop();
        } else{
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: this.translate.get("close-appFine"),
            message: this.translate.get("sure-want-leave"),
            buttons: [
              {
                text: this.translate.get("yes"),
                role: 'cancel',
              },
              {
                text: this.translate.get("yes"),
                handler: () => {
                  this.platform.exitApp();
                }
              }
            ]
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  display(range: number = 5) : void {
    let keys = this.pdata.keysGetter(this.pdata.notifications_handled).reverse();
    let index : number = this.position;
    for(index; index < this.position + range && index < keys.length ; index++) {
      let guid : string = keys[index];
      let notification : CNotification = this.pdata.notifications_handled[guid];
      this.diplayed_notifications_handled.push(notification);
    }
    this.position = index;
    this.display_handled = true;
  }

  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.display();
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the content of your `app.component.ts` file? So we can take a look at what's going when the app starts...

Comment: Post updated. But I don'k know why it's important ?

Comment: Provide your ionic info output. Is it possible to upgrade your Ionic's version to a new one? It's currently in 3.4.0 already, using Angular 4 (I guessi 2.1 is still using Angular 2, which does not have some improvements).

Comment: Sure, I already think about that. But I'm afraid that upgrade can disturbed all my app.

Comment: If you upgrade to Ionic v3 you can add lazy loading to your app. This should further improve the loading speed, but it requires a lot of changes within your app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating Ionic v3 and as indicated by Andreas Gassmann implementing lazy loading like is shown [here](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-3-lazy-loading/) and building with --prod option. The loading time has passed from more than 12s to less than 4s in device.